# Generate markup for jquery tabs using marionette views

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, marionette, backbone-views, jquery-tabs

I want to generate a markup for jQuery tabs using Marionette Views like so:

```
<div id="tabs-container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">TWO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">THREE</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <h2>Content heading 1</h2>
        <p>DATA</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">
        <h2>Content heading 2</h2>
        <p>DATA</p>   
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-3">
        <h2>Content heading 3</h2>
        <p>DATA</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

DATA: 
I've a collection of data I receive from the server that shall be used to populate the tabs - like so.

```
ItineraryCollection: 
[
    day1: {DATA},
    day2: {DATA},
    day2: {DATA},
]
```

I want to create a tab like so using `$('#tab_container').tabs()` using jQuery tabs function:
[image: Mock up for tabs I want to generate from above]

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not a direct answer to your question, I've covered generating markup for external libraries on my blog here: http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/02/03/tutorial-nested-views-using-backbone-marionettes-compositeview/

That post shows you how to use Marionette to create the markup to display a collapsible view. You should be able to easily adapt the concepts to your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it is helpful to understand the concept and adapt. I did check it, however I was looking for any specific answer w.r.t jQuery tabs as I assumed that it must one of the most commonly used UI element and if there was a 'accepted'/best way to generate this markup.

Comment: The problem is there are many "commonly used" UI libraries (jQuery UI, Bootstrap, Kendo UI, etc.) each with its own markup. Luckily, the linked post should enable you to go from Backbone data entities to any DOM structure you need for these UI libraries.